# MPAndroidChart - Line chart is no longer filling entire view after changing the number of data points

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm having an issue in my app where adding a large number of data points, clearing them, adding a smaller number of datapoints causes the `LineChart` to not completely reach the end of the view.

I recreated this issue with a simple `LineChart`.

[image]

In the linechart, I first add 365 data points by clicking the `Add 365` button and it successfully loads all the points into the `LineChart` view with a width of `300dp`.

Next, I click the `Add 25` button to load the 25 data points into the `LineChart`, but as you can see the line no longer reaches the end of the view for some reason.

I thought this might be because the chart is zoomed all the way out, so I added `lineChart.fitScreen()` but it doesn't do anything.

So I'm no longer sure what the problem is. Does anyone know what I'm doing incorrectly?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.linechart)
    LineChart lineChart;

    private final List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    private LineDataSet dataSet;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, null);
        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.gradient_purple);
        dataSet.setFillDrawable(drawable);
        dataSet.setLineWidth(1.5f);
        dataSet.setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(false);
        dataSet.setHighLightColor(Color.WHITE);
        dataSet.setHighlightLineWidth(1.5f);
        dataSet.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.teal_700));
        dataSet.setDrawFilled(true);
        dataSet.setDrawCircles(false);
        dataSet.setDrawValues(false);

        lineChart.setMinOffset(0f);
        lineChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
        lineChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
        lineChart.getXAxis().setEnabled(false);
        lineChart.setNoDataText(null);
        lineChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
        lineChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        lineChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_add_25)
    void onAdd25() {
        dataSet.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            Entry entry = new Entry(i, i);
            dataSet.addEntry(entry);
        }
        LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSet);
        lineChart.setData(lineData);

        //lineChart.fitScreen(); Adding fitScreen doesn't do anything
        lineChart.invalidate();


    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_add_365)
    void onAdd365() {
        dataSet.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
            Entry entry = new Entry(i, i);
            dataSet.addEntry(entry);
        }
        LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSet);
        lineChart.setData(lineData);

        //lineChart.fitScreen(); Adding fitScreen doesn't do anything
        lineChart.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/purple_500"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:text="Test App"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/linechart"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_25"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
        android:text="Add 25"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_365"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        android:text="Add 365"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Using version: `implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** - Call `dataSet.calcMinMax()` after clearing and updating its data with a smaller dataset.

For whatever reason, the dataset is not clearing its min/max X & Y values when you call `dataSet.clear();`, so when you had a dataset with X max of 364, adding a new dataset that only goes to 24 still keeps that old maximum, and the chart is drawn to that bound. The easy fix is to call `calcMinMax()` on it manually yourself after filling it with smaller data set (or always as a best practice), like this:

```java
dataSet.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    Entry entry = new Entry(i, i);
    dataSet.addEntry(entry);
}

// if you print out dataSet.getXMax() here, it shows 364 if
//  you plotted the 365 point data set already

dataSet.calcMinMax();

// dataSet.getXMax() here will now be correct
```

Another approach, which is more robust to the dataset saving state like this, would be to generate a new dataset for each call. You could define a helper function to apply the formatting that takes a list of entries, like this:

```java
private LineDataSet createDataSet(List<Entry> entries) {
    LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, null);
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.gradient_purple);
    dataSet.setFillDrawable(drawable);
    dataSet.setLineWidth(1.5f);
    dataSet.setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(false);
    dataSet.setHighLightColor(Color.WHITE);
    dataSet.setHighlightLineWidth(1.5f);
    dataSet.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.teal_700));
    dataSet.setDrawFilled(true);
    dataSet.setDrawCircles(false);
    dataSet.setDrawValues(false);
    return dataSet;
}
```

then remove the `dataSet` and `entries` class members and calls to them in `onCreate` and instead do something like this on `onAdd25` and `onAdd365`

```java
void onAdd365() {
    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
        Entry entry = new Entry(i, i);
        entries.add(entry);
    }
    LineDataSet dataSet = createDataSet(entries);
    LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSet);
    lineChart.setData(lineData);
    lineChart.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I plan on using your solution of doing it with the helper function instead. It's working well and is also much better than what I was doing. Thanks!